# If I have one kafka server running How many replication factor for a Topic I can have?

Tags: apache-kafka

How many replication factor we can have for one topic and one server?

Comment: What happened when you tried to create more than one replica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replication factor allows to configure how many brokers host a replica (a copy) of each partition.

So if you have a single Kafka broker, the replication can only be 1.

Comment: Mickael Maison Thanks.